# GPGPU - CUDA: global store efficiency

Tags: cuda, gpgpu, coalescing

I am trying to figure out how well the global memory **write** accesses of one of my kernels are coalesced, based on the "**global store efficiency**" value of NVidia's profiler (I am using CUDA 5 toolkit preview release, on a Fermi GPU).

As far as I understood, this value is the ratio of requested memory transactions to actual nb of transcations performed, therefore reflects whether accesses are all perfectly coalesced (100% efficiency) or not.

Now, for a thread block width of 32, and taking float values as input and output, the following test kernel gives 100% efficiency both for global load and for global store, as expected:

```
__global__ void dummyKernel(float*output,float* input,size_t pitch)
{
  unsigned int x = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
  unsigned int y = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
  int offset = y*pitch+x;
  float tmp = input[offset];
  output[offset] = tmp;
}
```

What I don't understand is why when I start adding useful code in between the input read and the output write, the global store efficiency begins to drop, whereas I have not changed the memory write pattern or the thread block geometry ? The global *load* stays at 100%, as I expect, though.

Could someone please shed a light on why this happens ? I thought, since all 32 threads in a given warp execute the output store instruction simultaneously (by definition) and using a "coalescing-friendly" pattern, I should still get 100% whatever I do before, but obviously I must be misunderstanding something on either the meaning of global store efficiency, or on the conditions for global store coalescing.

Thx,

EDIT :

Here is an example: if I use this code (just adding a "round" operation on input), global store efficiency drops from 100% to 95%

```
__global__ void dummyKernel(float*output,float* input,size_t pitch)
{
  unsigned int x = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
  unsigned int y = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
  int offset = y*pitch+x;
  float tmp = round(input[offset]);
  output[offset] = tmp;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with `useful code in between`?

Comment: Why did you suggest that efficiency begins to drop?

Comment: That is indeed mysterious. As you did, I would not have expected the global store efficiency to change. I guess you haven't changed the logic so that the store only happens for some of the threads?

Comment: Please provide complete code. Otherwise any answer or comment here is only speculation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, shame on me, I found the problem: I was profiling this simple test code in Debug mode, which gives completely wild numbers for most metrics. Re-profiling in Release mode gave me the expected result : 100% store efficiency in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

Unsure if this is the case, but round probably converts its argument to a double and if there is a register spilling, then each thread would access 8 bytes of memory, which would then be coerced into 4 bytes of tmp. Accessing 8 bytes would reduce the coalescing to half-warp.

However, I believe register spilling shouldn't happen since the number of local variables in your kernel is small. You could check with nvcc --ptxas-options=-v for the spill.

Comment: I checked just to be sure and as expected there is no spilling (21 registers used). Even if there was somekind of a double/float cast, I still would not understand how it can affect the final write which uses a float in any case. I will check the assembly code to try and figure out the difference...